# Trying to Change the color of the background label in ListView

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, .net

I am trying to change the color of the background when twa is at different values but it with my current code, the data is not firing, but when I remove the

```
   <asp: Label id="TWAlabel" OnDataBinding="ListView2_OnDataBinding">
```

But when I remove OnDataBinding the data fires, so I have no idea what is wrong. I am doing this in Asp.net(C#), JavaScript, and the data is sourced from an Access database. Here is my code:

```
 <style>
    .YellowThis
    {
    background-color:yellow;

 } 

 .RedThis
  {
 background-color:red;
 }

    .GreenThis  
    {
background-color:green;
 }

</style>        <asp:ListView id="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"  EnableViewState="False">

    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <span style="background-color: white;color: #333333; border: 2em; border-width:1em; border-color:black;">
    Plant Name:
    <asp:Label id="PlantLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plant") %>' />
    <br />
    Department #:
    <asp:Label id="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
    <br />
    Department Name:
    <asp:Label id="GroupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Code:
    <asp:Label id="Job_CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Code") %>' />
    <br />
    TWA:
    <asp:Label id="TWALabel" OnDataBinding="ListView2_DataBinding" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TWA") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Classification:
    <asp:Label id="Job_ClassificationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Classification") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Function:
    <asp:Label id="Job_FunctionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Function") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Description:
    <asp:Label id="Job_DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Description") %>' />
    <br />
    <br />
    </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
    <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server"  style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; border:3em; border-color:black;">
    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: left;background-color: white;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration:underline ;color: #FFFFFF;" >
    </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
    <span style="background-color: white;font-weight: bold;color: #333333;">
    <u>Plant Name</u>:
    <asp:Label id="PlantLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plant") %>' />
    <br />
    Department #:
    <asp:Label id="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
    <br />
    Department Name:
    <asp:Label id="GroupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Code:
    <asp:Label id="Job_CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Code") %>' />
    <br />
    TWA:
    <asp:Label id="TWALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TWA") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Classification:
    <asp:Label id="Job_ClassificationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Classification") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Function:
    <asp:Label id="Job_FunctionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Function") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Description:
    <asp:Label id="Job_DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Description") %>' />
    <br />
    <br />
    </span>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>


    <script runat="server">
    protected void ListView2_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Label lbl = (Label)(sender);
 int TWA = (int)(Eval("TWA"));
lbl.Text = TWA.ToString();
if (TWA >= 85)
{
    if (TWA < 90)
    {
        lbl.CssClass = "YellowThis";
    }
    else
    {
        lbl.CssClass = "RedThis";
    }
}
else 
{
lbl.CssClass="GreenThis";
}
 }
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Why do you have 3 `<style>` tags? 2. Please trim down your code to a snippet.

Comment: I have trimmed it down and fix the style errors, but my problem still exists

Comment: I won't mind if I have to delete the function I have and do something completely different, it can be a javascript function, or a c# function, I would just like to have a function that works that changes the color of the background based on the TWA values. Thank you for any help that is given

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in your code behind. Iterate through your list items.

```
protected void add_color()
{

foreach(ListItem li in ListView2.Items)
{ 
       Label your_label = (Label)li.FindControl" your_label_name";      
       int TWA = Convert.ToInt32(your_label);



   if (TWA > 90)
                {

                       your_label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow 

                }

}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am kind of new to this, what exactly do you mean by all the label controls?

Comment: So far what I have tried with your suggestion has not worked. any other suggestions

Comment: You just put the color changing logic in its own method and then then call it after you bind the listview. So if you are binding the list in your page load then you would call this method after that.

Comment: check out the edit. Then you just do that for every label control in your list. Then call that method after you call the method that binds your list.

Comment: Any other suggestions you have?

Comment: No that's all i got. I can't use javascript in the server controls I program so I have to do everything from code behind.

Comment: Does any know how to do this possibly in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This questions is more than 1 year old and I'm not sure if it'll help anyone here.

I think what went wrong in your code is because your listview databinding event was created in Label instead of creating it in the Listview.

What you can do is create a databinding event in ListView control and read the value of the TWA label and then set your ListView control background color.